# Why cant I install Visual Studio Express 2013 on Windows 7 SP1?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-7, installation, visual-studio-express

I am trying to install Visual Studio Express 2013 on my fresh Windows 7 install. I have Service Pack 1, and have applied a bunch of other updates also, but it states that my version of Windows isn't new enough. I am under the impression that so long as I am on Windows 7 + SP1, it should install? What else am I missing? (This is definitely for Windows Desktop, and not for Windows (phone). I have tried downloading the Desktop installer multiple times to make sure of this.)

Here is the log file it spits out: [HERE](http://pastebin.com/ghDAmGrt)

Side Note, Visual Studio Community gives the same problem, and I think this should be OK on Windows 7 SP1 also?

Comment: Your OS version comes back: OSVersion: 6.1.7600.0 windows 7 SP1 should be: 6.1.7601, so it looks like you're missing SP1

Comment: I defintely ticked SP1 in the windows update panel the other day and let it installwith a reboot... I can no longer see SP1 as an option in windows update either... how would I go about getting SP1 if it clearly didnt work?

Comment: Try downloading and installing  it manually: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5842